# Did Noah say Shirah on seeing the drowning of the wicked?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach, noach-noah-the-man

The Israelites said Shirah on seeing the wicked Egyptians drowning.

Did Noah act in a similar way, praising God for saving him and his immediate family and seeing millions of wicked humans drowning in (boiling?) flood?

Comment: Did he see it? Were there windows looking down?

Comment: @rosends sideways maybe

Comment: @rosends there are those who explain the disagreement about the tzoar, whether a window or a precious stone, based on the differing opinions if Noach was truly righteous, and would deserve to see the people drowningthrough a widow, or if he was only righteous compared to his generation, and thereby did not deserve a window, so he had the precious stone. But in either case, he wasn't saved from the people drowning and so he would not have said a shir, akin to the angels by the yam suf.

Comment: @user6591 A good point, maybe post it as an answer, I liked it. You're saying that the Shirah is said specifically on own salvation and not simply God's judgment.

Comment: @user6591 But if the Israelites said it on on their salvation why would the angels protest?

Comment: @al The angels didn't protest. They also wanted to say shir and Hashem stopped them and said 'my handiwork is drowning, and you want to sing?'. Which begs the question why could klal yisroel say shiur. The answer given is that klal yisroel were being saved from the ones who tormented them and deserved to sing.

Comment: @user6591 I was thinking more logistically -- the tzohar was (I thought) near the top which would have made it difficult to see facing down.

Comment: @rosends That may be true. Or it was in the front or the back which are not mentioned as being slanted. I was simply mentioning something I've seen.

Comment: Considering the interpretation of some that he got drunk after the flood to attempt to forget his sorrow and survivor's guilt, it seems unlikely. Also, arguably, many of these people were relatives.

Comment: @user6591 I redacted the question to reflect your comments. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe he did, maybe he didn't. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Noach  did not say Shira when they drowned.

The Malochim  were  criticized for saying Shira when the Egyptians were drowning.

Klal Yisroel was not criticized because the Egyptians had been their tormenters who had been running after them so they were also thanking Hashem over their salvation.Noach was not being chased after by the people of his generation.

Chazal discuss the opposite question. Why didn't Noach  daven for his generation? He is even criticized by them not having done so. But he clearly didn't say Shira upon their destruction.

Comment: Thank you. 1. Do you have sources, or are those your speculations? 2. When one person is saved out of millions I would see it appropriate to praise God or something. 3. Extermination or the punishment of the Egyptians was prophesied long before, so the drowning wasn't so surprising, after all.

Comment: The Melochim being told not to say Shira when the Egyptians were drowning is a Gemara  Megillah 10B. I no longer remember   where the other sources are

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary. Rav Chaim Friedlander זצ"ל in his שפתי חיים על פרשת נח, brings from the זוהר (השמטות בראשית רנד) that when נח came out of the תיבה and saw the destruction, he cried out to ד' asking why He hadn't had mercy on the people

> כשיצא מן התיבה וראה את העולם חרב והתחיל לבכות לפניו ואמר רבש"ע נקראת רחום, היה לך לרחם על בריותיך! השיבו הקב"ה ואמר רעיא שטיא, השתא אמרת דא? למה לא אמרת בשעתא דאמרית לך כי אותך ראיתי צדיק לפני וכו ואח"כ עשה לך תבת עצי גופר וכו לא עאל בלבך למבעי רחמין על ישובא עלמא?

On the other hand, Rav Dovid Kviat זצ"ל in his סוכת דוד suggests, in order to explain a מדרש, that the קרבן which נח brought after the מבול was not just to thank G'd for saving him, but also out of recognition that everything G'd does is fair, even a destruction brought about by Him.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *machlokess* if the *tzohar* is a window or a precious jewel. The *darshanim* say as follows: There is also a *machlokess* if *tamim haya be'dorosav* means that only in his generation, but had he been in the generation of Avraham then he would have been considered as naught. Others say that all the more so had he been in the generation of Avraham he would have been considered to be a great man. The *darshanim* say that according to the opinion that he was truly great, then he was allowed to see the downfall of his generation and the *tzohar* was a window. However if you say he was not truly great then the *tzohar* was a jewel, as he was not allowed to look out at the downfall of his generation.

I don't think that either way he would have said *shirah*, as per @Schmerel.